# #1067 - Invalid default value for 'date'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following field in a CREATE TABLE statement:

```
`date` DATETİME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'date'

How can i fix that problem?

Comment: Looks like you have a single quote in there.

Comment: Upgrade to MySQL 5.6 that can take that kind of defaults? 5.5 can't, not sure which inbetween version added it.

Comment: MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 works fine, while 5.5 fails.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.6.5 [added that default syntax for datetime](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2012/05/29/overlooked-mysql-5-6-new-features-timestamp-and-datetime-improvements/), previously it was only available for TIMESTAMP.

In other words, you most likely need to change your datatype or upgrade your MySQL.